# How can I create a function to make this step easier in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have a DataFrame that looks like this below:

| ID | Clicks | Clicks_GA | Discrep_% | Discrep_Found |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5939 | 18482 | 18480 | .01 | False |

#Calculates the discrepancy % (I also import numpy as np)

`df['Discrep_%'] = np.absolute(df['Clicks'] - df['Clicks_GA']) / (df['Clicks_GA']  * 100)`

#Returns true or false if the discrepancy is less than the abs value of 5%

`df['Discrep_Found'] =  (df['Discrep_%'] > .05)`

The problem is that I have multiple dataframes, and I don't want to copy and paste the same line of code a bunch of times.

Is there a function I can use to make this process simpler?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def count_some(df):
    val = np.absolute(df['Clicks'] - df['Clicks_GA']) / (df['Clicks_GA']  * 100)
    return val, val > .05

df[["Discrep_%", "Discrep_Found"]] = df.apply(count_some, axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the DataFrames. For example:

```
for df in [df1, df2, df3, ...]:
    df['Discrep_%'] = np.absolute(df['Clicks'] - df['Clicks_GA']) / (df['Clicks_GA']  * 100)
    df['Discrep_Found'] =  (df['Discrep_%'] > .05)
```